# How to customize mat-paginator dropdown position?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I make use of a material `<mat-paginator>` inside of my component and according to the requirements I need to adjust its position so that the list of options lies under the selected one. Here is what I need to achieve:

[image]

However, the default position of mat-options looks like this:

[image]

Inspecting the DOM Tree I can find `<mat-select>` inside of the `<mat-paginator>`. `<mat-option>` list seems to be rendered pretty much the same, it's being hosted inside DIV node with a class `cdk-overlay-pane`.

But while `<mat-select>` API allows me to provide `panelClass` property in order to apply additional CSS classes to the dropdown panel, `<mat-paginator>` does not.  Also, I can't use `::ng-deep` because I want to target only this dropdown and do not overwrite others.

Here is [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eatgku?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpaginator-overview-example.ts) with mat-paginator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just provide [MatSelectConfig](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelectConfig) service at desired level (Component, Module or root) setting `disableOptionCentering` to `true`, using [MAT_SELECT_CONFIG](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MAT_SELECT_CONFIG) Injection Token.